# Error 500: Internal Server Error, if external css has been connected in grails

Tags: css, grails, groovy

I write web-application in Grails. For example, I connect external css with such method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resourse(dir:'css', file:'header.css')}" type="text/css">
```

But when I run my application, such error occures:

"Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI:/myAppName/startPage/indexClass:groovy.lang.MissingMethodExceptionMessage:No signature of method: C__grails_myAppName_grails_app_views_startPage_index_gsp.resourse() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[dir:css, file:header.css]] Possible solutions: resource(), resource(groovy.lang.Closure), resource(java.util.Map), resource(java.util.Map, groovy.lang.Closure), resource(java.util.Map, java.lang.CharSequence)"

This is my css's content:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#header {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #111111;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #111111;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #111111;
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: its `resource` and not `resourse`

Comment: The clue is where it says `Possible solutions: resource()`